# Getting an error(InvalidClassException) while executing a distributed load test from Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter

The Master and Slave are present on Linux servers. I am getting an error as mentioned below while executing a Load Test from Jenkins. The same test is working fine when I execute it from Master at Linux server.

```
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Tue Oct 11 01:54:49 CDT 2022 (1665471289297)
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 242, local class serialVersionUID = 243
Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
```

PS: Jmeter versions, Java versions, configuration of ports across all servers is configured.

Comment: Looks like you use 2 different versions of jmeter

Comment: Hey Jens, if I had been using 2 different versions, I would have faced error from Linux Environment too but that is working fine as I said earlier

Comment: Not if you have different versions in master and salve

Comment: Different versions in the instances? how can I verify this?

Comment: search for the jmeter jars and compare it

Comment: That seems fine too

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have different JMeter versions on master and slaves, JMeter cannot properly perform [serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization) hence you're getting the error

To be absolutely sure that everything works fine:

1. Use the same [Java](https://openjdk.org/) version everywhere
2. Use the same JMeter version everywhere, it's recommended to use [the latest](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. If you're using any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - they need to be installed on all the slaves. Again plugins versions must be exactly the same
4. If you're using any external data (CSV files, files used for uploading, any other form of test data) - it needs to be copied to all slaves before starting the test

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Hello Dmitri! there is no difference in Jmeter versions, Java versions, plugins versions. I am able to test the entire set-up successfully from Linux environment, but getting the mentioned error only from Jenkins

Comment: Hello ASingh, I'm not supporting you anymore because you're lying at my face

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf6KO.png